# Are 'erwählen' and 'sich erwählen' interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I came across the following paragraph in *Der Spiegel*:

> Wahrscheinlich ist die Fifa einfach ein hoffnungsloser Fall. Neuanfang, Umbruch, Zeitenwende - all die großen Worte, die rund um den Amtsantritt von Gianni Infantino gefallen sind, sind gleich beim ersten Check als Luftnummern enttarnt worden. **Der Beschluss des Kongresses von Mexiko-Stadt, sich die Kontrolleure des Reformprozesses selbst erwählen und auch wieder feuern zu können - das ist beste Politik im Sinne des skandalösen Amtsvorgängers Joseph Blatter.**

dict.cc gives the following English translations for *erwählen*:

> erwählen = elect, choose; sich (Dat.) etw. erwählen = choose sth. (for oneself)

I would like to know if omitting *sich* in the sentence highlighted in bold above would still be grammatically correct.

Comment: Note that the verb _erwählen_ is of a very high register and arguably not suitable here (it may be irony, though). More common choices would be _bestimmen_, _wählen_, _aussuchen_.

Comment: @chirlu Could you please remind me what you mean by "of a very high regiser"?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29 for a definition of _register_. In this case, I wanted to say that _erwählen_ could be expected in poetic or literary language, but not in a standard news magazine text. It doesn’t fit in with informal terms such as _Check_, _Luftnummer_, _feuern_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the sentence without *sich* would still be grammatical.